# Consume form data by wcf service sending by post

Tags: asp.net, wcf, forms, post

I read some articles about this and I find that to achive that wcf get data from post request we add

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1 {
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(
      Method = "POST",
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
      UriTemplate = "/GetData")]
  void GetData(Stream data);
}
```

and in implementation

```
public string GetData( Stream input)
{
    long incomingLength = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.ContentLength;
    string[] result = new string[incomingLength];
    int cnter = 0;
    int arrayVal = -1;
    do
    {
        if (arrayVal != -1) result[cnter++] = Convert.ToChar(arrayVal).ToString();
        arrayVal = input.ReadByte();
    } while (arrayVal != -1);

    return incomingLength.ToString();
}
```

My question is what should I do that in submit action in form request will send to my service and consume?

In Stream parameter will I have post information from form to which I could get by Request["FirstName"]?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code isn't decoding the request body correctly - you're creating an array of `string` values, each one with one character. After getting the request body, you need to parse the query string (using `HttpUtility` is an easy way to do so). The code below shows how to get the body and one of the fields correctly.

```
public class StackOverflow_7228102
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "/GetData")]
        string GetData(Stream data);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string GetData(Stream input)
        {
            string body = new StreamReader(input).ReadToEnd();
            NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(body);
            return nvc["FirstName"];
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Console.WriteLine(c.UploadString(baseAddress + "/GetData", "FirstName=John&LastName=Doe&Age=33"));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's great solution Tnx ;) But in Test method You invoke service and send to it post request. It is possible (and smart way of do it) to invoke service method after submit in form like <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8000/Service/GetData"> ? If I do it like that it will works ? :)

Comment: Yes, it should work (the test methods simulates what a HTML form post would send). The thing is that when you do a form submit by default you should create a HTML page to send it back (instead of a simple string), otherwise the browser will only show you the string back. Another option is to use some ajax call in the form submit, then you can get the result back as XML (or JSON) and update the page inline.